# How to share a gradle file across many projects within an organization

Tags: java, gradle

How to share a gradle file across many projects within an organization. I would prefer if license.gradle is part of a separate repository, so that changes like copyright information can be changed in a single location instead of each project in an organization

```
apply from: 'license.gradle'
```

e.g all of the following repositories has this file right now

```
github.com/myorg/project-a
github.com/myorg/project-b
github.com/myorg/project-c
github.com/myorg/project-d
```